# Plotly: Date format problem in hover text field

Tags: python, plotly

I am plotting Gannt chart using plotly express timeline function. I am having problems with the hover text rendering of the date field.

```
plotly version: 4.5.4
```

The original example given here https://plotly.com/python/gantt/, the *Finish* field renders in the right format as `%Y-%m-%d` .

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource="Alex")
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Resource")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.show()
```

I tried customizing the hover text fields using the below code.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource="Alex")
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Resource"
                  , hover_data={"Start": True, 
                              "Finish": True, 
                              "Task": True, 
                              "Resource": False}
                 )

fig.show()
```

Now, the *Finish* field shown is the difference of `Start` and `Finish` in milliseconds. In the above example the 'Finish' value is shown as **5011200000**.

I need the original `Finish` value to be shown in the hover text. In this case `2009-02-28`.

I could only solve this by creating a copy of Finish column in my dataframe and use that for the hover text.

Is there a way I get the correct rendering of the column without duplicating it?

Answer (score 6):

You can change the format of the values shown in the hover tooltip using `hovertemplate`, see this [example](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#modifying-the-hovertemplate-of-a-plotly-express-figure) on the Plotly website as well as the Plotly [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#scatter-hovertemplate).

I included an example below based on your code, where the start date and end date are both in `%Y-%m-%d` format. Note that `x_start` and `x_end` correspond to the `base` and `x` keys in the Plotly figure dictionary.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-01', Finish='2009-04-30', Resource="Anna")
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Resource")

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate="Start: %{base|%Y-%m-%d}<br>"
                                "End: %{x|%Y-%m-%d}<br>"
                                "Task: %{y}")

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The hovertemplate does solve the problem of formatting, but I loose the ability to show another field from the dataframe. For instance, if I had a Priority column that I wanted to show in hover text, can it be done using the hovertemplate?

Comment: Yes you can do that with `hovertemplate` and `customdata`, see this example https://chart-studio.plotly.com/~empet/15366/customdata-for-a-few-plotly-chart-types/#/.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems there is bug logged for the issue I am facing. https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2518. I was using hover_data to render the data in the same dataframe. With hovertemplate, I will have to create a copy or a different Dataframe to render additional fields. I will keep duplicate field for now.